# Can somebody help me make the two toolbar's divs to appear on the same line?

Tags: html, line, toolbar

So my code is this:

```
<div id="toolbar">
<div style='border: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>
    <font color="#fff">
        <marquee bgcolor="#000" direction="left" loop="25" width="95%">Welcome to 

the NabzZzolution Mercenarie Group of the AboveUltimate-HydraBlast Server! If you are a 

member please register yourself.</marquee>
    </font>
</div>
<div>
    <a style="text-align:left;"class="wsite-button wsite-button-small wsite-button-

highlight" href="http://aunabzzzolution.weebly.com/log-in.html" target="_blank">
    <span class="wsite-button-inner">Log In</span>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

and how they appear : http://aunabzzzolution.weebly.com/
So i want the log in button to go at the toolbars 1st line, and the marqeee thing to be on it's right side. Can somebody please help me?
Thank you in advance for any help.

Sincerely,
Tasos Papalyras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `display:inline-block;`

```
button {
   display:inline-block;
   // other props here
}
```

Comment: ok wait it dont fits on the tooldbar properly, i ll try to fix it..

Comment: eeem it doesnt appearing corretly, cause the button is kinda bigger than the marqueee and the toolbar, i think its 30, and toolbar is 25. can sb help me make the button exceed the toolbar, and not the marquee??? ...How it appears: aunabzzzolution.weebly.com

Comment: can you use? `position:absolute; top:2px; left:3px;`

Comment: well, please upvote and accept! and i give a check on your site ;)

Comment: http://aunabzzzolution.weebly.com/ yay:)

Comment: @TasosTzakrisPapalyrasDM missed upvote though :/

Comment: well buddy what is your site for?

Comment: what is upvote? I just created an account here, cause i needed help, :) If u explain to me what upvote is, i ll do it for sure :)

Comment: My site is about a group, at a san andreas-multiplayer server called above ultimate, and I am a 14 year old member of it, and,since i know html css and stuff, i decided to create and moderate a website for it :)

Comment: at the left of each answer there is up and down blackish arrows! upvote is up arrow and downvote is down arrow! upvote means that this answer helped me and downvote means that answer didn't helped me ot its wrong and you have to click upvote though ;)

Comment: oh that? I cant cause , as i said, i just created my account and i dont have the reputation to do that. sorry :/

Comment: well its ok :) my aim was to help you

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS attribute: `display` with a property of `inline` or `inline-block`.

Modified version (also formatted correctly):

```
<div id="toolbar" style="display:inline">
    <div style='border: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;display:inline;'>
        <font color="#fff">
            <marquee bgcolor="#000" direction="left" loop="25" width="90%">
                Welcome to the NabzZzolution Mercenarie Group of the AboveUltimate-HydraBlast Server! If you are a member please register yourself.
            </marquee>
        </font>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="display:inline;">
    <a style="text-align:left;"class="wsite-button wsite-button-small wsite-button-highlight;" href="http://aunabzzzolution.weebly.com/log-in.html" target="_blank">
        <span class="wsite-button-inner">Log In</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/L8JfJ/

Comment: @TasosTzakrisPapalyrasDM Sorry, should be fixed now (edited answer)!

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<font style="display: inline-block; width:80%">  // <== inline-block and width.
  ...
</font>

... 

<div style="text-align:left; display:inline-block">      // <== inline-block
    <div style="height: 10px; overflow: hidden;"></div>

    <a class="wsite-button wsite-button-small wsite-button-highlight"  href="http://aunabzzzolution.weebly.com/log-in.html" target="_blank">
        <span class="wsite-button-inner">Log In</span>
    </a>
    <div style="height: 10px; overflow: hidden;"></div>
</div>
```